# Posicionamento de botão no bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Tenho um site baseado num template *bootstrap*, em uma das páginas adicionei um botão e por mais que eu dê o comando pra ficar alinhado à direita, ele sempre fica à esquerda e desalinhado em relação ao formulário.

[Meu código](http://tratspay.com/app/meus-afiliados.html):

```
<div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <fieldset class="form-group">
              <label>Produto:</label>
                                      <select class="form-control form-control-line">
                            <option>-- Selecione --</option>
                            <option>Nome do Produto A</option>
                            <option>Nome do Produto B</option>

                          </select>
          </fieldset></div>
          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <fieldset class="form-group">
              <label>Ocultar afiliados sem vendas</label>
                                      <select class="form-control form-control-line">
                            <option>-- Selecione --</option>
                            <option>Sim</option>
                            <option>Não</option>

                          </select>
          </fieldset></div>
          <div class="col-lg-4">
           <label>Classificar por::</label>
                                      <select class="form-control form-control-line">
                            <option>-- Selecione --</option>
                            <option>TOP Afiliados</option>
                            <option>Afiliados mais antigos</option>Novos Afiliadoss
                              <option>Afiliados com mais tráfego</option>


                          </select>
          </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn">Filtrar</button>

        </div>
```

Comment: você está utilizado col-lg-4 para cada select, altere para col-lg-3, incluido o botão, assim você subdivide o grid de forma correta.

Comment: Muito obrigado, Getulio!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>A pesar da baixa qualidade da sua pergunta, acho que posso presumir que esteja relacionado ao botão "Filtrar". É importante que adicione tais informações na sua pergunta, tal como trazer a parte do código para a pergunta.</strike>

---

Você inseriu o botão diretamente na linha do *grid* do *Bootstrap* (`.row`). O correto é adicionar uma coluna (`.col`) como *container* do seu botão. Aí você pode estilizar essa coluna posicionando o conteúdo onde quiser.

```
<div class="col-lg-12" style="text-align: right;">
    <button type="button" class="btn">Filtrar</button>
</div>
```

Repare que adicionei a classe `.col-lg-12` que acaba ocupando as 12 colunas do grid. Para mais detalhes, vide a documentação do Bootstrap (link no final da resposta). Adicionei, também, o estilo `text-align: right` a fim de posicionar seu botão do lado direito. Adicionei direto no elemento (hard-coded), mas o melhor é fazer isso direto no arquivo de estilo do seu site (`.css`).

Veja o resultado:

[image: Print]

> Leitura recomendada: [Bootstrap - Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado! Ajudou muito! Ainda estou aprendendo a programar.

Answer (score -3):

No Bootstrap 5 ele substitui o text-left e text-right por text-start e text-end

Passei a mesma situação e resolvi utilizando o text-end